# How to approximate square root of sum of two squared polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I was wondering if it is possible to approximate the coefficients $c_i$ in the expression
$$
\sqrt{({\sum_{i=1}^{3}a_ix_i})^2+({\sum_{i=1}^{3}b_ix_i})^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{3}c_ix_i
$$

where $a_i$, $b_i$, and $x_i$ are real.

Comment: Since you are linearizing, you need a point ($x=x_0$) for linearization, a.k.a. taylor expansion.

Comment: Easier, would be to express the left side as $\sum\sum c_ic_jx_ix_j$. though it would turn the approximation trivial.